# Cannot find php files while browsing website from local network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server

I have a webserver 192.168.0.116 and my local laptop ip is 192.168.0.101 
ping work server access works but while trying to browse the website showing the below page. 
Website: http://www.eco2.ca
But it is working fine in https://www.eco2.ca

Find the vhost file output in apache:

```
root@mail:~# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-eco2.ca.vhost 

<Directory /var/www/eco2.ca>
        AllowOverride None
                Require all denied
        </Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>

                                    DocumentRoot /var/www/eco2.ca/web

        ServerName eco2.ca
        ServerAlias www.eco2.ca
        ServerAdmin webmaster@eco2.ca

        ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/eco2.ca/error.log

        Alias /error/ "/var/www/eco2.ca/web/error/"
        ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
        ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
        ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
        ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
        ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
        ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
        ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        </IfModule>

        <Directory /var/www/eco2.ca/web>
                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                        SetHandler None
                </FilesMatch>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web>
                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                        SetHandler None
                </FilesMatch>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>




        # cgi enabled
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client2/web2/cgi-bin>
                        Require all granted
                    </Directory>
        ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/ /var/www/clients/client2/web2/cgi-bin/
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|pl)$">
            SetHandler cgi-script
        </FilesMatch>
        # suexec enabled
        <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
            SuexecUserGroup web2 client2
        </IfModule>
        # php as fast-cgi enabled
    # For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html
        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                FcgidIdleTimeout 300
                FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
                # FcgidMaxProcesses 1000
                FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 5000
                FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
                FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 10
                FcgidConnectTimeout 3
                FcgidIOTimeout 600
                FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
                FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
        </IfModule>
        <Directory /var/www/eco2.ca/web>
                <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                    SetHandler fcgid-script
                </FilesMatch>
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
                Options +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client2/web2/web>
                <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                    SetHandler fcgid-script
                </FilesMatch>
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web2/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
                Options +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                        </Directory>



        # add support for apache mpm_itk
        <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
            AssignUserId web2 client2
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
        # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
            <Directory /var/www/clients/client2/web2/webdav>
                <ifModule mod_security2.c>
                    SecRuleRemoveById 960015
                    SecRuleRemoveById 960032
                </ifModule>
                <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                    SetHandler None
                </FilesMatch>
            </Directory>
            DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client2/web2/tmp/DavLock
            # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
            # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
      # WEBDAV BEGIN
            # WEBDAV END
        </IfModule>



</VirtualHost>




root@mail:~#
```

[Webpage output from local network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxyOw.png)

[ping result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P84Bk.png)

[Host file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLdWd.png)
[Https url output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOCvH.png)

What is the solution for this ?

Comment: is there index file exist ?

Comment: All file exists.